# Fedora 15 / Electric / Build Issues / Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo, ros-electric, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all
I just installed an Electric desktop-full as per the instructions on an x86_64 Fedora 15 installation. ROS seems to have installed fine.
However, whenever I attempt a rosmake simulator_gazebo, or any other package that requires eigen as a dependency, I get the error

```
rosdep install ERROR:
failed to install eigen
```

I have eigen3-devel installed (eigen3-devel-3.0.0-2.fc15.noarch) and don't really have a clue how to go about this, as apparently eigen doesn't have any compiled libraries, only the headers.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

UPDATE: It seems that the warning is thrown only because it can't really find it by the name it's looking for. For example, after a little playing around, I could get vision_opencv working.

UPDATE 2 : Now after quite a few hours, I'm stuck at a cmake stage. Had to install yampl-cpp-devel, tinyxml-devel, vtk-devel, libyaml-devel, rosdep install for gazebo_tools, build assimp, copied the /usr/include/ffmpeg/* to /usr/include (to fix missing avformat.h), hdf5-devel, [added -ltinyxml flag to  /gazebo/build/CMakeCache.txt (and in gazebo_tools), added a VTK_DIR:FILEPATH=/usr/lib64/vtk-5.6 to pcl_ros/CMakeCache.txt ... Didnt work], used http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2006-March/008633.html and changed VTK REQUIRED to VTK5 required in the cmake files. Also changed the path in the URL file to point to lib64/vtk-5.6

This fixed the missing VTK errors, but I'm repeatedly stuck with the tinyXML errors.

```
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'TiXmlElement::SetAttribute(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char,    std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)' is defined in DSO /usr/lib64/libtinyxml.so.0 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib64/libtinyxml.so.0: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
```

I also get a (possibly related because it involves pcl_ros_tf)

```
  [ 28%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  Linking CXX shared library lib/libvision_reconfigure.so
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcl_ros_tf
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[2]: *** [lib/libvision_reconfigure.so] Error 1
  make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/vision_reconfigure.dir/all] Error 2
```

Where do I add the -ltinyxml flag?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11671/fedora-15-/-electric-/-build-issues-/-gazebo/) by [ICodeRaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/793/icoderaven/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2011-10-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Got a solution / workaround: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5170

---

Originally posted by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) with karma: 735 on 2011-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ICodeRaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/793/icoderaven/) on 2011-10-31**:
Great job! I'll just try it out!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Those are the little things that indeed make the ROS installation quit a bit harder on non-Ubuntu systems. I managed to get it all to compile on my system here (also fc15 x86_64), but should warn you that, for gazebo, I'm stuck with a nasty segfault that seems not so easy to solve: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5170

As for stage, I never tried to build it here, and a make command there now also fails here, even at an earlier stage (this is tags/stage-1.4.0):
patch -d build/Stage-3.2.2-Source -p0 < Stage-3.2.2-Source.patch;
patch: **** rejecting target file name with ".." component: ../Stage-3.2.2-Source/libstage/CMakeLists.txt
make[1]: *** [build/Stage-3.2.2-Source/unpacked] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/u0063509/electric/stage'
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (message):
Build of Stage failed
So I can't help you for that.

For tinyxml: did you try reinstalling the library? I have tinyxml and tinyxml-devel installed and never had any problems with those.

And the last error, about the pcl_ros_tf linking, looks like pcl_ros_tf is not correctly build, hence the linking error?

Let me know the outcome of your attempt!

---

Originally posted by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) with karma: 735 on 2011-10-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ICodeRaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/793/icoderaven/) on 2011-10-26**:
Figured the deal with pcl_ros_tf. I had to delete the previous CMakeFiles folder. But tinyxml is still giving issues!

**Comment by [ICodeRaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/793/icoderaven/) on 2011-10-26**:
Nope, no dice. Tinyxml is present, and is in lib64. Also, I can't seem to find pcl_ros_tf. But perception_pcl builds without errors. :S

**Comment by [ICodeRaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/793/icoderaven/) on 2011-10-26**:
It's good to know that there are other suffering souls :) I'll try out your recommendations, and get back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To fix the libtinyxml issue, apparently the build process doesn't look at the lib64 folder. So,  I added  to CMakeLists.txt

```
set(GAZEBO_LDFLAGS_OTHERS -L/usr/lib64 -ltinyxml)
set(GAZEBO_INCLUDE_DIRS ${GAZEBO_INCLUDE_DIRS} /usr/include)
```

to the beginning,
and a

```
  rosbuild_add_link_flags(bin/urdf2model ${GAZEBO_LDFLAGS_OTHERS})
```

for the urdf2model executable

I also had to something very similar in gazebo_tools, same initial commands, and a

```
rosbuild_add_link_flags(bin/urdf2model ${GAZEBO_LDFLAGS_OTHERS})
```

For the pcl_ros_tf, apparently an old failed build was blocking a successful build, and so a delete of the build and the CMakeFiles folder and a subsequent rosmake did the job.

---

Originally posted by [ICodeRaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/793/icoderaven/) with karma: 76 on 2011-10-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on 2011-10-26**:
Yes - this looks *very* similar!

**Comment by [ICodeRaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/793/icoderaven/) on 2011-10-26**:
http://pastebin.com/zuzDimdP I have an additional error message. Is this something similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219167/stdmap-segfaults-when-using-operator

**Comment by [ICodeRaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/793/icoderaven/) on 2011-10-26**:
Yup, SIGSEGV :/

**Comment by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on 2011-10-26**:
Are you able to succesfully run Gazebo?